# How do I restart Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, restart

Sometimes I want to reload chrome settings or just generally restart chrome, but I don't want to loose any open tabs. How can I restart chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restart chrome, in the omnibox (address bar) you can type the following and it will restart:

```
chrome://restart
```

For all URLs that chrome supports, see:
https://www.ghacks.net/2012/09/04/list-of-chrome-urls-and-their-purpose/